# Stack Overflow links decoration - only https, not http

Tags: discussion

I put the following text into the question body or answer body

```
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233980
```

Then I edit this text into

```
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233980
```

Initially link looks like that

- [Firebird database schema/data difference tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233980)

But after the edit the link looks like that.

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233980

Funny thing is, in the preview box while I still editing, both links look identically, borrowing the target page TITLE. But after the edit is posted, only HTTPS link is decorated to the page TITLE and the plain HTTP get suddenly reverted to raw URL.

I wonder if there is some decision behind this distinction or preview and posting are two independent (copy-pasted?) subroutines, that got out of sync.